# What can I say about the minimum and the maximum value of $n $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

Let $a_1,...,a_n $ positive integers s.t. $a_1+...+a_n=2011$, where $n $ is a positive integer,  $n\geq3$ and $a_1\leq |a_2-a_3|$, $a_2\leq|a_3-a_4|$,..., $a_n\leq|a_1-a_2|$.

What can I say about the minimum and the maximum value of $n $?

I notice that the minimum value of $n $ is greater then 3. They are equal?

Comment: I think that the sequence will not exist. Let $a_i$ be the largest element in this sequence, then $a_i \geq a_{i+1}$ so $a_i > a_{i+1} - 1 \geq |a_{i+1} -
 a_{i+2}|$.

Answer (score 2):

*(Expanding on [Hw Chu's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2652210/what-can-i-say-about-the-minimum-and-the-maximum-value-of-n#comment5478018_2652210)):* There is no
solution at all, not even with  real numbers $a_i > 0$.

Without loss of generality (by rotating the indices if necessary)
assume that $a_1$ is the largest number in $a_1, \ldots, a_n$.

Then
$$
 a_1 \le |a_2 - a_3| = \max(a_2, a_3) - \min(a_2, a_3) < a_1 - 0 = a_1
$$
gives a contradiction.

*Remark:* There are solutions if the condition “positive integers”
is relaxed to “non-negative integers”, see [Solving $a_1+...+a_n=2011$ , $a_1\leq |a_2-a_3|, \ldots a_n\leq|a_1-a_2|$ with non-negative integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2653428/solving-a-1-a-n-2011-a-1-leq-a-2-a-3-ldots-a-n-leqa-1-a-2-with-n).