# Solving $a_1+...+a_n=2011$ , $a_1\leq |a_2-a_3|, \ldots a_n\leq|a_1-a_2|$ with non-negative integers

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, alternative-proof

Let $a_1,...,a_n $ non negative integers s.t. $a_1+...+a_n=2011$, where $n $ is a positive integer,  $n\geq3$ and $a_1\leq |a_2-a_3|$, $a_2\leq|a_3-a_4|$,..., $a_n\leq|a_1-a_2|$.

This problem is similar to [What can I say about the minimum and the maximum value of $n $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2652210/what-can-i-say-about-the-minimum-and-the-maximum-value-of-n), only that
here the $a_n$ are allowed to be zero.

I have an answer but I am not sure if it is right.

I have to take two cases: $a_3\leq a_2$ or $a_2\leq a_3$.

If $a_3\leq a_2\Rightarrow |a_2-a_3|=a_2-a_3\Rightarrow a_1\leq a_2-a_3\Rightarrow a_1\leq a_2\Rightarrow |a_1-a_2|=a_2-a_1\Rightarrow a_n\leq a_2\Rightarrow a_{n-1}\leq|a_n-a_1|\leq a_2\Rightarrow...\Rightarrow a_4\leq a_2\Rightarrow |a_3-a_4|\leq a_2.$

But $a_2\leq |a_3-a_4|$. Then $|a_1-a_2|=|a_3-a_4|=...=|a_n-a_1|=a_2$.

So  $a_1=a_3=a_5=...=0$ and $a_2=a_4=a_6=...$.

Therefore $k\cdot a_2=2011\Rightarrow a_2=1$ and $k=2011$ $\Rightarrow n=4022$.

The other case is similar.

I don't want to post it but I am just curious!!!
It is right my argument?

Comment: No. There is no solution in positive integers

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen If I take $1,0,1,0,....,1,0$ it works

Comment: @Problemsolving $a_i$ is required to be positive.

Comment: @almagest For me positive integers means natural numbers.

Comment: @Problemsolving 0 is not a positive integer. Positive means $>0$.

Comment: $0$ is neither positive, nor negative.  So you can't use $a_i = 0$.

Comment: I do not understand why this is so heavily qownvoted. It is a clear question for proof-verification, showing more effort than many other questions. So pointing out the error ("positive" vs "non-negative") as a comment or answer should be sufficient.

Comment: @MartinR I see no reason for this either. Perhaps it's just the way the title is presented...

Comment: @Problemsolving:  I have taken the liberty to edit your question, hoping to make it clearer. Please check the edit.

Comment: @Martin R Thank you!!

Comment: @Problemsolving Now that you have changed the question to allow 0, you are correct, it is easy to get a solution by alternating 0 and 1. Since 2011 is prime, that is the only way to go (although of course you can start with 0 or with 1).

Comment: Why is $a_{n-1} = |a_n - a_1| \le a_2$ ?

Comment: @Martin R $a_{n-1}\leq |a_n-a_1|\leq$ max{$a_n,a_1$}$\leq a_2$.

Comment: @Martin R 1,1,1...,1 is not solution.

Comment: @Problemsolving: You are right, that was nonsense. But a 0 can be followed by one or two 1s: "0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, ..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conclusion

> Then $|a_1-a_2|=|a_3-a_4|=...=|a_n-a_1|=a_2$.

is not correct, as can be seen by considering the sequence
$$
 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, \ldots 1, 0
$$
but I think you were close.

Let
$$
 x = \max(a_1, \ldots, a_n)
$$
The $a_i$ cannot all be equal, so (by rotating the indices if necessary)
we can assume that $a_1 = x$ and $a_n \ne x$.

If $a_2 \le a_3$
then
$$
 x = a_1 \le a_3 - a_2 \le x \Longrightarrow a_2 = 0, a_3 = x \, .
$$
Otherwise
$$
 x = a_1 \le a_2 - a_3 \le x \Longrightarrow a_2 = x, a_3 = 0
$$
which implies
$$
 x = a_2 \le |a_3 - a_4| = a_4 \le x \Longrightarrow a_4 = x \, .
$$
So the sequence starts either with
$$
  x, 0, x, \ldots
$$
or with
$$
 x, x, 0, x, \ldots
$$
Now the same argument can be repeated with $a_3=x$ or $a_4=x$, 
respectively, and one sees that the entire sequence consists of
the “building blocks”
$$
   x, 0 \quad \text{and} \quad x, x, 0 
$$
which can be arbitrarily combined. Finally, since the sum of
all elements is $2011$ (which is a prime number), we necessarily have
$x = 1$.

Therefore the solutions are exactly the sequences 
made of the building blocks
$$
   1, 0 \quad \text{and} \quad 1, 1, 0 
$$
with a total number of $2011$ one's (and rotations thereof).